# Transferring money from mom's account for Express entry proof of funds

Tags: immigration, canada, skilled-migration, express-entry

I have an express entry profile but at the moment I do not have 13000 CAD in my bank account to show as proof of funds. When I receive the invitation, would it be possible for me to transfer account from my mother's account to mine and show that as proof of funds? will they consider that as parking money? If not, if I have a joint fixed deposit with my mom for the required money, will that help? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would the money be a gift or a loan?

Comment: The funds arrive in your account just after the invitation is made, with no provenance and applicant's earnings insufficient to explain the money? An account with someone else's name on it as well? If I were the visa examiner, I'd certainly conclude this was indeed money parking.

Answer (score 3):

The timing may be an issue and your financial documentation may not fully support or meet what is expected (added emphasis mine).

> [**Proof of funds – Skilled immigrants (Express Entry)**](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/proof-funds.html)
>
> You must show that you have enough money to settle in Canada to meet the minimum requirements of:
>
> - the Federal Skilled Worker Program or
> - the Federal Skilled Trades Program
>
> ***You can’t borrow this money from another person. You must be able to use this money to pay the costs of living for your family (even if they aren’t coming with you).***
>
> If your spouse is coming with you, you can count money you have together in a joint account. You may be able to count money in an account under their name only, but you must prove you have access to the money.
>
> If you are invited to apply, you must give written proof that you have this money.
>
> **What we accept as proof**
>
> Funds must be readily available to you. For example, you can't use equity on real property as proof of settlement funds.
>
> The funds must be available both when you apply and when (if) we issue you a permanent resident visa. You must prove to an immigration officer that you can legally access them to use to settle here when you arrive.
>
> For proof, you must get official letters from any banks or financial institutions where you are keeping money.
>
> Letter(s) must:
>
> - be printed on the financial institution’s letterhead
> - include their contact information (address, telephone number and email address)
> - include your name
> - list outstanding debts such as credit card debts and loans
> - include, for each current bank and investment account:
>        ○ account numbers
>        ○ the date each account was opened
>        ○ the current balance of each account
>        ○ ***the average balance for the past six months***